# ReactJs Registration using SpringBoot RestApi

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

My Backend code is working correctly while testing with Postman. However, when I use my React app it shows a 400, and in IntelliJ it logs the following:

> WARN 1264 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved
> [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
> Required request body is missing: public
> org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.msys.smartkart.config.GenericResponseDto>
> com.msys.smartkart.controller.UserController.addUser(com.msys.smartkart.entity.User)
> throws java.lang.Exception].

```
@GetMapping("/register")
public ResponseEntity<GenericResponseDto> addUser(@RequestBody User user) throws Exception {

    final boolean isNotExists = userService.findUserByEmailAddress(user.getEmailAddress());

    if (isNotExists) {
        userService.registerUser(user);
        log.info("User saved successfully");

    } else {
        log.warn("User is Already exists");
        throw new Exception(user.getEmailAddress() + "Already Exists");
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new GenericResponseDto(200, "User Registered"), HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
}
```

```
 const submitHandler = () => {
    fetch(
      `http://localhost:8080/register?` +
        new URLSearchParams({
          name: name,
          emailAddress: emailAddress,
          mobileNumber: mobileNumber,
          password: password,
          confirmPassword: confirmPassword,
          address: address,
        })
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.statusCode === 200) {
          console.log(res);
          console.log(res.responseData);
          setData(res.responseData);
        } else {
          alert("Somthing went wrong try again");
        }
      });
  };
```

**What is causing this behaviour?**

Comment: I think you are preparing the request params instead of request body. There is difference. That is why you are facing missing body

Comment: Thank You , I m very new to react the issue got solved